# Feeding an input stream with EOF

Tags: c, io

I am building a small shell interpreter which executes various commands, and I accomplish this by forking my process.

However, I want the child process to stop waiting for input in the standard input stream, and it does so by expecting an EOF. How do I push an EOF deliberately into that stream?

More specifically, if I am looping on this condition:

```
while (fgets(&input, 1024, stdin) != NULL) { // .....
```

How can I cause it to become false?

Comment: You need to give more info. Is the child's stdin connected to the parent (a.k.a. a coprocess)? Or...?

Comment: @Chris EOF is normally a #define for -1

Comment: It's probably marginally better to say EOF than -1, but I don't know that it matters most of the time.

Comment: What makes you think putchar(-1) will do anything like what the questioner wants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure of what your shell is doing - but I would have thought the the way of doing this would be to close the "standard input stream" in the child side of the `fork()` and then do not bother reading from it again. If you have forked a child to do something, why does it drop back into the main input handling loop.

In psuedo code

```
if (pid = fork())
{
    // parent - wait for child to do it's thing and then process another command
}
else
{
    // child
    close(0);
    // do some sort of command processing and then exit 
}
```

Comment: sounds reasonable. How do I "close" the stdin in C?

Answer (score 1):

The normal method is to close the stream at the sending (parent) end.

Comment: How did you open it? Normally, you would use the close() system call or similar.

Comment: like I said, I'm just reading chars from the stdin with fgets()

Comment: So the parent isn't providing the child with data? I think you need to describe your architeture in a bit more detail in your question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't you just close the other end of the pipe?